# Using setImageBitmap without changing the shape of ImageButton

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-imagebutton

My camera app has a circular ImageButton to show the last image captured by the user like many other camera apps. To give the ImageButton a circular shape I'm using a style that uses a drawable for background and I'm using setImageBitmap function of ImageButton to show image thumb. but the problem is that the ImageButton's shape changes to square after setting the bitmap. how can I do this without changing the shape of ImageButton?

Comment: use circleCrop transformation on the image if you are using image processing library like Glide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [circular Image view](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) library to achieve that

```
<CircularImage.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profilecircularimage"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/cameraImage"
                app:civ_border_color="@color/primary"
                app:civ_border_width="2dp" />
```